SQL Timeout Error with Svelte Node App during building
I have a Svelte app with a MariaDB database which I want to dockerise. To query the database from the website I use the following code:
const pool: Pool = mariadb.createPool({
    host: DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    user: DB_USER || 'root',
    password: DB_PASSWORD || 'ADMIN',
    database: DB_NAME || 'coffeeCloudDB',
    port: MARIADB_DOCKER_PORT || 3306
});

export async function getAllCoffees(): Promise<Coffee[]> {
    const itemList: Coffee[] = [];
    try {
        const conn = await pool.getConnection();
        const query = `
        SELECT c.id, c.coffee_name as name, c.description, false as favorite
        FROM coffees as c
        `;
        conn.end();
        const result = await conn.query(query);
        return result[0] as Coffee[];
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return itemList;
    } finally {
        pool.end();
    }
}

in preview mode with a running database everything works fine. But as soon as I want to build the website I get the following error:
SqlError: (conn:-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10001ms
    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=10)
    at module.exports.createError (/app/node_modules/mariadb/lib/misc/errors.js:66:10)
    at Pool._requestTimeoutHandler (/app/node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool.js:354:26)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:581:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7) {
  sqlMessage: 'retrieve connection from pool timeout after 10001ms\n' +
    '    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=10)',
  sql: null,
  fatal: false,
  errno: 45028,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}

This also happens when I use the following compose file:
services:
  web:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
    depends_on:
      mariadb:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: True
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules



  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=ADMIN
      - MARIADB_USER=root
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized" ]
      start_period: 5s
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER=mariadb
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"

volumes:
  db:

with ‘docker compose up --build’. In this case, the website is built first, which causes the error, then the database is started, and then the website is started. The website is still accessible afterward, but no further attempt is made to load the data via SQL, even if the database could now be accessed.
I am currently using the mariadb package for the connection, previously I had a similar error message with mysql2, which indicates the same problem.
In addition to the other package, I also tried to intercept the error message with try and catch, but that didn't lead to any other results either

The hostname in compose is the servicename, so use DB_HOST=mariadb. Recommend also moving to non-root users on MARIADB_USER/MARIADB_PASSWORD as this will automaticly be granted all permissions on MARIADB_DATABASE.
